# fbthrift folly/folly/stats/test won't build on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, thrift, folly

We installed Ubuntu 14.04.

We want to install fbthrift there.

We did the git clone of fbthrift.

We then did a git checkout of version v2017.06.05.00.

We followed the guidance in README.md, and ran the script called ./build/deps_ubuntu_14.04.sh

It dies trying to build fbthrift/thrift/build/deps/folly/folly/stats/test
saying "*** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop."

It just finished successfully building in .../folly/folly/io/test.

Interestingly, io/test has a Makefile.am, a Makefile.in, and a Makefile.
stats/test only has a Makefile.am.

I don't know where in this automated script the "autoconf" and "automakers" steps were supposed to be executed on stats/test.

Help?

Comment: I would just create an issue on their GitHub repository site.

Comment: Good idea, thanks.